# Azure Schedule Long Running Tasks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-scheduler

We use azure and we have a lot of schedules that run.

Schedules that send emails, do database processing and similar.

Now we were using the Azure scheduler, however if the schedule doesnt finish in the timeout period, it runs it again, this causes us issues.

So what is the best way of running say a daily email schedule that takes hours to run without the timeout forcing it to run again.

The schedule is just hitting a URL of our ASP.NET MVC app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at Azure Web Jobs?

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Seems like they would do the job for you?